# WinForms ComboBox problem

Tags: c#, winforms

Here is the task. I have a combobox with 2 values(DAY and NIGHT), label and a timer. Timer fires every second and takes combobox.Text value and puts it into label.Text. The problem is when I drop window with options (DAY, NIGHT) and hover a mouse over one of them it gets selected into label. This is not the desired behaviour, how can I get rid of it and show only actual value selected in combobox, not hovered one?

Comment: Don't use a combobox with only 2 items.  Use radio buttons.

Comment: @Hans That's good advice, but it's not always practical to use radio buttons for space/clutter considerations. They are also a bit 'dated' looking IMO.

Comment: Was the answer below acceptable?  If so - you should accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `combobox.SelectedValue` property instead of `combobox.Text`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using a bad practice.

You should update your label on ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged event, and not on timer - if your case is not just theoretical model to practice .NET logic.